# tcl interpreter parameters contaminated

Tags: multithreading, tcl, segmentation-fault

I have a multithreaded C++ program in which the main thread creates two tcl interpreters, interp#1 and interp#2. During parallel running, the main thread and one slave thread each try to invoke different cmds through interp#1 and interp#2 seperately. At some point, memory error happens and program crashes. 
The log file tells me that some value of kObjv[] for interp#1 is contaminated by that for interp#2. 
I also run helgrind to check possible data races and it dumps plenty of data race risks on beneath tcl lib apis, like: Tcl_NewStringObj/TclFreeObj/ResetObjResult/TclNREvalObjv, etc.

It looks like the underlying memory is shared by interpreters from same thread. Is that true? My program links static tcl 8.6 lib, which was installed with thread enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tcl library uses thread-bound memory pooling to (hugely!) reduce pressure on global locks, with the consequence that every Tcl interpreter object is also strongly bound to the thread that created it. (This is the Apartment Threading Model, if you're familiar with that.) You *cannot* safely use a Tcl interpreter from any other thread. If you want to have access to a Tcl interpreter in each thread, each thread should create its own interpreter and use that.

There are a few operations that allow safe inter-thread communication, specifically `Tcl_ThreadQueueEvent()` and `Tcl_ThreadAlert()`, which allow you to lodge a message for the other thread to handle when it is ready (every thread with a Tcl interpreter on it has an event queue associated with it inside the Tcl library; this is in the core of the Tcl event notifier engine).

You're recommended to use the Tcl thread package (which should be part of any good Tcl 8.6 installation and is available for older versions too) for inter-thread working in Tcl. Apart from the complexity of getting each side to know what the handle for the other thread is, it's really quite easy to use.